# How to train a model in R using multiple datasets

Tags: r, model, r-caret

I have a large list of datasets (~1000) of the following form:

```
data.frame(seq = sample(c("M","K","A","I","G"), 15, replace = T), replicate(10,runif(15)), response = sample(0:1,15,rep=TRUE))
```

A (protein) sequence with 10 related features and a binary response variable.

Now I would like to train a model which learns from a certain amount (2/3) of these datasets. Is the only way to do this using rbind to get them into one big dataset? I'd prefer to have them separate as this is sequential data (the sequences exhibit sequential correlation. Nearby x and y values are likely to be
related to each other.) A sliding window will also be implemented for this reason.

I'm using caret but so far I haven't found a way to iteratively train a model. This would be the start:

```
nn = lapply(dataset_list[1:10], function(x) b(x))

b <- function(mydata){
  dd <- as.data.frame(mydata)
  result <- train(dd[,c(2:11)],dd[,12], error.criterium="LMS", report=TRUE, show.step=100, n.shows=5, method = "nnet" )
  return(result)
}
```

Comment: What kind of model are you trying to "train" here? Most models in R expect all the data to be in a simple data.frame. If you are worried that combing your data will hide otherwise un-modeled "features" of your data, then you are likely not choosing the right model for your data. If you need help choosing a model, consider posting to [stats.se] instead where discussions of statistical methods are on-topic.

Comment: @MrFlick Most similar approaches have used neural networks (in combination with a sliding window). I'm trying to figure out how to set it up correctly in R, but perhaps R has some limitations when considering those types of models. I will consider posting to Cross Validate, thank you.